# is there a function in python to solve my requirement

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe

```
    dff.head()
+---+----------+-----------------+--------------+------------+
|   | owner_id | purchase_points | return_point | push_toke  |
+---+----------+-----------------+--------------+------------+
| 0 |      123 |            77.0 |          0.0 |            |
| 1 |      546 |             0.0 |         16.0 | Abc97grwe  |
| 2 |      789 |             5.0 |         15.0 | cst84ask   |
| 3 |      697 |            89.0 |          6.0 | abc7532asd |
+---+----------+-----------------+--------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to get an status column to say if purchase_point is >0 then say "Purchased", if return point>0 and push_token != np.nan i want "Yes, Never purchased" and rest to say "No"

I tried the below if loop but find below error:

```
def my_fun(organic, seeded, push_token):
if dff['purchase_points'] > 0: 
    return 'Yes Answered'
elif [dff['return_point'] > 0 | dff['push_token'] == np.nan]:
    return 'Yes, Never answered'
else:
    return 'No'
dff['status_1'] = dff.apply(my_fun('organic', 'seeded', 'push_token'))
```

error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please help with the solution, thanks in advance

Comment: Also instead `dff['push_token'] == np.nan` use `dff['push_token'].isna()`

Comment: They closed the cuestion. But you can see one way to do it here
https://gist.github.com/frannievas/5933863605d9709c170615f0878e8028